# AskAI encounter an error after installing in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, openai-api, chatgpt-plugin

Hello I'm trying to install ChatGpt in eclipse but after installing it ask AI gives error.
I followed the instruction  from https://github.com/gradusnikov/eclipse-chatgpt-plugin
This is the error message which I receive.

```
Unable to run the task: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Request failed with status code: 404 and response body: jdk.internal.net.http.ResponseSubscribers$HttpResponseInputStream@4edc67a0
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Request failed with status code: 404 and response body: jdk.internal.net.http.ResponseSubscribers$HttpResponseInputStream@4edc67a0
```

Can someone please look into it and let me know what can be done here

[image: The error message which I received]

Comment: [HTTP status code 404 means "Not Found"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404). The AskAI plugin failed to send an HTTP request because it does not exist anymore or because something is blocking the request (are you behind a proxy?). For more details, please go to the _Error Log_ view, select the error, hit Ctrl+C and paste it into your question formatted as _Sample Code_.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and was driven to this page
https://github.com/gradusnikov/eclipse-chatgpt-plugin/issues/4

Hope it help!